# Is this code equation solvable?

Tags: disassembly

Assuming the following lines of code:

```
 MOV DWORD PTR FS:[0],EAX
 CALL someRoutine
 MOV EAX,DWORD PTR DS:[EAX+4]
 CMP DWORD PTR DS:[EAX+1204],0
 JE placeInCode
 XOR EAX,EAX
```

My goal is to change [someRoutine] in such a way that the JE is always taken - I specifically don't want to tamper with the code outside [someRoutine]. So just think of [someRoutine] as a set of instructions that you can freely change and adapt.

I can't seem to understand how to solve this equation. If there was no MOV instruction after the call, I guess I could just go to the address [EAX+1204] and fill it with 0. But like this, there seem to be too many unknown dependencies.

Any advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have `someRoutine` perform the following actions (in C below for example purposes) --

```
DWORD* p = (DWORD*)malloc(8);
p[0] = 0;
p[1] = (SIZE_T)p - 1204;
return p;
```

Obviously this is a memory-leak since the allocated memory never gets `free()`'d, so you wouldn't want to use this approach if `someRoutine` gets called often. However it's not feasible to offer a better recommendation without us knowing the memory layout of the actual program.

***Edit:*** Updated based on @tathanhdinh's suggestion.

Comment: Maybe I am wrong, since the degrees of freedom of this equation is 2 (they are value of EAX and the memory); we may need just a 8 bytes malloc, for example: 
`dword* p = malloc(4 * 2); p[0] = 0; p[1] = (dword)p - 1204; return p;`

Comment: @tathanhdinh: Nice thinking! I've updated my answer above. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks a lots @JasonGeffner. I think we can just change `malloc` by a stack allocation, then we may not have memory leak, for example: `dword a; dword b = 0; a = (dword)&b - 1204; return &b;`

Comment: @tathanhdinh: That assumes that the returned data is evaluated immediately after `someRoutine` is called. If @vic wants to make this work for each call of `someRoutine` throughout the program, I don't know that it's safe to assume that the stack values will never get overwritten between the `someRoutine` call and the check.

Comment: Ahhh, you are absolutely right @JasonGeffner. I did not take into account the situation that you described.

Comment: Frankly, I wouldn't know how to translate this into an asm patch. But that doesn't seem to matter anyway since the routine is called almost with every single program action. So it's back to the drawing board for me. But I appreciate the answer.